# MySQL grouping by week, based on a date column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a date column and I would like to try and group by, using a week as a time reference in order to count how many rows occured per week. I have done this for days, using GROUP BY Date(`Date_Column`) but i'm unsure how to do this by week?

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar question to this, but wanted to group data from multiple date columns showing the weekly total for each of those. This question here covers that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563659/mysql-group-by-week-num-w-multiple-date-column

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ....
GROUP BY YEAR(Date_column), WEEKOFYEAR(Date_Column);
```

Comment: Thank you, i just found the Week() function and then read the comment above about different years.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put a `GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_column)` at the end of your query - this will take in consideration also the year the date is in.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT week(Date_Column)
FROM ....
GROUP BY week(Date_Column);
```

Comment: what about same week number in different years?

Comment: The other answers already seem to address that issue pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2017-01-01"),YEARWEEK("2017-01-01"),WEEK("2017-01-01");
```

Outputs:

```
WEEKOFYEAR("2017-01-01")    YEARWEEK("2017-01-01")  WEEK("2017-01-01")
52                          201701                  1
```

Looks like `YEARWEEK` is the best solution. No need to concat the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(Date_Column),'/',WEEK(Date_Column)) AS efdt 
FROM ....
GROUP BY efdt;
```