# mysql group by week, based on int dateid(yyyymmdd)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read several questions like [MySQL grouping by week, based on a date column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533471/mysql-grouping-by-week-based-on-a-date-column).

But my date type is int(11)(I can't change the structure) to store something like **20150101** to represent **1st Jan,2015**. How should I use [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) method to group by based on this?

Like:

```
select week(SOMETHING_TO(dateid)) as weeknum, game ,count(*) 
from table where game is not null group by weeknum , game order by weeknum desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to first change your `int(11)` value to `date` and then use the `Week` function ie,

```
select WEEK(DATE(dateid)) as weeknum, game ,count(*) 
from table
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/1568)

EDIT:-

As per your comments you may try to use

```
select concat('last ' ,(WEEK(dateid,1) -WEEK(CURDATE(),1)),' week',' ' )
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/1597)

Also check the [WEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function in detail.

> The two-argument form of WEEK() enables you to specify whether the
>   week starts on Sunday or Monday and whether the return value should be
>   in the range from 0 to 53 or from 1 to 53. If the mode argument is
>   omitted, the value of the default_week_format system variable is used.

Also see this list for reference:

```
M   F.day   Range   Week 1 is the first week …
0   Sunday  0-53    with a Sunday in this year
1   Monday  0-53    with more than 3 days this year
2   Sunday  1-53    with a Sunday in this year
3   Monday  1-53    with more than 3 days this year
4   Sunday  0-53    with more than 3 days this year
5   Monday  0-53    with a Monday in this year
6   Sunday  1-53    with more than 3 days this year
7   Monday  1-53    with a Monday in this year

M = Mode
F.day = First day of week
```

Comment: I can't change the structure of the db

Comment: @Jaskey:- You dont have to change the structure for this. I am asking you to use the FROM_UNIXTIME function

Comment: But I had tried something like : FROM_UNIXTIME(20150101) , it returns 1970-08-22 14:15:01...

Comment: @Jaskey:- Updated my answer. Initially I thought that the dateid is an integer. But your int column is in a dateformat so you need a DATE fucntion for it. Please try the updated query.

Comment: Yes, it should work. Would you please update you answer it a little bit so that i shows "last n week" as the weeknum since it will be more helpful to others and I will accept your answer

Comment: Your description says you are changing it to `datetime` but you are actually changing it to `date`. Minor technicality, but for clarity's sake...

Comment: @Jaskey:- I am not sure if I got that clearly. Although updated my answer a bit

Comment: @RahulTripathi, actually I mean `select concat('last ' ,(WEEK(dateid,1) -WEEK(CURDATE(),1)),' day',' ' ) `, please also inform the reader that the `WEEK` function begins from SUNDAY by default so if I want it from Monday . I should use WEEK(date, 1)

Comment: @Jaskey:- Good point, however feel free to to update or edit the answer!